# iOS launch app with environment variable

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, environment-variables

My app requires device UDID, but iOS simulator doesn't have one. So I want to pass a mock device UDID as a environment variable for simulator. I already know how to set environment variable in Xcode and it works fine when launching app from Xcode.

See tutorials:
[nshipster: launch arguments and environment variables](http://nshipster.com/launch-arguments-and-environment-variables/)
[cameronspickert: custom launch arguments and environment variables](http://cameronspickert.com/2014/02/18/custom-launch-arguments-and-environment-variables.html)

However, when I try to **launch app directly from simulator (not from Xcode)**, it seems no environment variables are passed to the app.

Question:
How to pass environment variable to app if launching app from simulator or device directly or even command line?

Comment: You wouldn't even be able to access the devices real UDID. The simulator can give you a UDID thats unique to you app but that is different when the simulator is reset. This is what the device will do too.

Answer (score 1):

The SIMULATOR_UDID environment variable contains the UDID of the simulated device, but you are probably doing something wrong if you try to use that as there is no direct analogy on device.

You can also setup your own environment variables by editing your scheme in Xcode.